# javascript variable inside indexOf

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reuse a function and I am defining a variable that is breaking the function when trying to put it inside of `indexOf()`. I've tried several approximations but I can't figure out why it's not working. The code is like this:

```
function toggleSelectAll(control, nadaValue) {
var allOptionIsSelected = (control.val() || []).indexOf('"' + nadaValue + '"') > -1;
```

In the case the function is breaking, `toggleSelectAll` is called like this:

```
toggleSelectAll($(this), 1);
```

trying to subsitute this one:

```
function toggleSelectAll(control) {
var allOptionIsSelected = (control.val() || []).indexOf("1") > -1;
```

You can see a couple of JSFiddle examples to illustrate better:

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/victorRGS/o8cjtoqp/1/

This doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/victorRGS/o8cjtoqp/2/

If you can throw some light on this it would be great! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try `.indexOf(nadaValue)`?

Comment: At first, remove the quotes around the variable name. Currently `indexOf` tries to find literal `"1"`. Then you need to either pass a string, or find `nadaValue.toString()`, since `indexOf` uses strict comparison.

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution, and is what @Teemu says, I had to convert `nadaValue.toString()` and it worked like a charm. Thanks for your answers. Should I leave this comment here or post a proper Answer comment?

Comment: Anyway, why the downvotes? I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` uses strict comparison when cheking the argument could be found from an array.

The data you have is type of string. However, you're passing a number as `nadaValue`, hence `indexOf` always fails to find a match from the array.

To fix this, you've either to pass a string as `nadaValue`, or explicitly convert it to a string before use in `indexOf`. A handy way would be to create a temporary string:

`(... indexOf(nadaValue.toString()) ... )`

This way you can preserve the number type, if it is needed later in the code.

Comment: That's the answer I need!

Comment: Another issue I ran into was that even if they are both strings, sometimes one of them will have hidden characters.  Calling a testString.trim() fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your code. `indexOf()` function uses strict comparison i.e. comparing with `'==='` which will compare data and datatype. So while comparing `nadaValue` it (`indexOf()`) is checking for literal 1 instead of String 1 i.e. "1".

Comment: The explanation is correct, but the fix is not. Whilst `indexOf("1")` works, your answer should not work?

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. I was considering 2nd fiddle as working example.Updated the answer.